# Upgrade did not complete successfully

Tags: 10.04

The upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 was interrupted prior to completion. What can I do to get my Ubuntu operating system working again.

Comment: This is an English web site, please state your question in English

Answer (score 0):

Boot in recovery mode, by holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, and then selecting *Advanced options* (if shown, if it's still 10.04 Grub it won't be there), and then selection the second entry *Recovery mode*.

This should boot to the recovery menu from which you can try:

```
dpkg Repair broken packages
```